# setTexture(_:resize:) not working for false parameter

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I have googled and played with xcode for a while now, and I was not able to match what the official documentation states for the resize parameter when set to false:

> If true, the sprite is resized to match the new texture. **Otherwise,
>   the size of the sprite is unchanged.**

I have the following example code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let someTexturedSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
    let carImage = SKTexture(imageNamed: "CarImage")

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        someTexturedSpriteNode.size = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
        someTexturedSpriteNode.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(frame.size.width)/2, y: CGFloat(frame.size.height)/2)
        addChild(someTexturedSpriteNode)

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        someTexturedSpriteNode.run(SKAction.setTexture(carImage, resize: false))

    }

}
```

However, the size of the sprite is in fact changing, despite the false bool.

Any suggestions on why the new texture is not staying at 100x100?

Many thanks!

Comment: Yeah that's odd that it still resizes the node's size. Any particular reason you need to use SKAction to set the texture? Can you just set the texture manually cause that works?

Comment: Hi Muffinman2497, no particular reason. I am just learning Swift and experiencing a little and it seemed very odd that this true/false parameter was making no difference at all. I guess it is a bug then.